# Retriving values and passing values between HTML and extjs View

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs

Is there any way to retriving values and passing values between HTML and extjs View?

An example
In html

```
<input id="text" type="text" value="book" style="width:80%" /><br />
```

In View

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
     items: {
     // created a windows but need some codes to call html by passing values, and after which retrieve data from html and getting values  
     id: text; 
     } 
}
```

The flow is that I want to change the input value from book to newbook. Then the view will get the code and return some values to the html again. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/). also you get use the native JS getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Sure that's possible. You can take a look at [`Ext.select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-select), which is a shorthand of [`Ext.dom.Element.select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-select). That selector creates a [composite element](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.CompositeElement), from where you can get the data etc.

```
var els = Ext.select("#some-el div.some-class", true);
// or select directly from an existing element
var el = Ext.get('some-el');
el.select('div.some-class', true);

els.setWidth(100); // all elements become 100 width
els.hide(true); // all elements fade out and hide
// or
els.setWidth(100).hide(true);
```

In your case it would mean you could use:
`var els = Ext.select("#text", true);`

If you want to change the `text property` of the item on the view you can use [`Ext.ComponentQuery`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery). Something like:
[`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#text')[0].setText('new value');`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query)

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't make it to work as the id is 'text' and it doesn't have a div class..@Tarabass

Comment: Yup I'm using the same codes too but nothing happens when editing the value in 'text'..`var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
     items: {
     id: 'text',                 fn: function() {
                    var el = Ext.select("#text",true); // nothing happens
                }
     } 
}` @Tarabass

Comment: You are just selecting the node and do nothing with it to update. Edited the answer again..

Comment: I am aware of setting the value part..but before setting the value, I think I am not able to pass the values as it does not ever seem to invoke this method at all `fn: function() { var el = Ext.select("#text",true); // nothing happens }`....@Tarabass